# Why does Bundler disapear after entering project directory with Puppet Installed RVM

Tags: rubygems, rvm, vagrant, bundler, puppet

This one is annoying/confusing.

**tl;dr**: *bundler gem disappears from gem list after entering rvm managed project directory, switching manually to the specified ruby makes it reappear, what gives?*

My goal is basically to have a few rubies installed all with access to bundler in their global gemsets so that I can quickly spin up my configured development box as I like it. The full source code in question is available here: https://github.com/neverstopbuilding/talon

The install seems to work correctly, however, when I have cloned a specific project, and cd into that directory, suddenly bundler disappears from the gem list and I can't run `bundle install`, here is some output from just a general project directory:

```
/vagrant/home/clients: rvm list

rvm rubies

   ruby-2.0.0-p643 [ x86_64 ]
=> ruby-2.1.5 [ x86_64 ]
 * ruby-2.2.1 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default

/vagrant/home/clients: ruby -v
ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [x86_64-linux]

/vagrant/home/clients: gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.2.4)
bundler (1.9.2)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
executable-hooks (1.3.2)
gem-wrappers (1.2.7)
io-console (0.4.2)
json (1.8.1)
minitest (4.7.5)
psych (2.0.5)
rake (10.1.0)
rdoc (4.1.0)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.4)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
test-unit (2.1.5.0)
```

Ok that's great, now when I cd into the actual project directory with only `2.1.5` in the `.ruby-version` file, and run the same commands, I get this:

```
/vagrant/home/clients/my_client/my_project (master): rvm list

rvm rubies

   ruby-2.0.0-p643 [ x86_64 ]
=> ruby-2.1.5 [ x86_64 ]
 * ruby-2.2.1 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default

/vagrant/home/clients/my_client/my_project (master): ruby -v
ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [x86_64-linux]
/vagrant/home/clients/my_client/my_project (master): gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.2.4)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
executable-hooks (1.3.2)
gem-wrappers (1.2.7)
io-console (0.4.2)
json (1.8.1)
minitest (4.7.5)
psych (2.0.5)
rake (10.1.0)
rdoc (4.1.0)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.4)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
test-unit (2.1.5.0)
```

Notice that bundler is missing from the above list, and of course running it results in `zsh: command not found: bundle`

Stranger still is that if I manually run `rvm use 2.1.5 and list the gems, I do get bundler, and I am able to run the bundle command.

**Why does this specific gem not load automatically when entering this project?** And how can I fix it... It seems silly to automate all of this stuff and still need to run commands manually to finish things.

### Other Relevant Info

#### Outside project directory:

```
: echo $PATH
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/vagrant/bin:/usr/local/bin::/usr/local/rvm/bin


gem env

/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/commands/environment_command.rb:151: warning: Insecure world writable dir /vagrant/home/clients/ in PATH, mode 040777
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.6
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.1.5 (2014-11-13 patchlevel 273) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/vagrant/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5
     - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - :benchmark => false
     - "gem" => "--no-ri --no-rdoc"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/bin
     - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/bin
     - /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /sbin
     - /bin
     - /usr/games
     - /usr/local/games
     - /home/vagrant/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     -
     - /usr/local/rvm/bin
```

#### Inside project directory:

```
: echo $PATH
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@my_project/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/vagrant/bin:/usr/local/bin:


: gem env
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/commands/environment_command.rb:151: warning: Insecure world writable dir /vagrant/home/clients/my_client/my_project/ in PATH, mode 040777
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.6
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.1.5 (2014-11-13 patchlevel 273) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@my_project
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@my_project/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/vagrant/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@my_project
     - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - :benchmark => false
     - "gem" => "--no-ri --no-rdoc"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@my_project/bin
     - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@global/bin
     - /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin
     - /usr/local/rvm/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /sbin
     - /bin
     - /usr/games
     - /usr/local/games
     - /home/vagrant/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
```

Comment: is there a `.ruby-gemset` file in that directory also?

Comment: yeah gemset file with "my_project" in it.